# slide Jquery without scroll bar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have an animation in my div that slide right to the left.
What I want is that animation, but without the scroll.

Is that the right way to do this animation? What is wrong? How can I disappear with this scroll bar?

CSS

```
#todoc{
 position:relative;
 min-width:250px;
 max-width:1030px;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin: 50px auto 0;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:red;
 padding:20px;

    right:-1000px;//for animation
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#todoc").animate({ right: '0'}, 'slow');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q637bLq5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `overflow: hidden` to `body`:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#todoc").animate({
    right: '0'
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
#todoc {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 1030px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
  right: -1000px;//for animation
}
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="todoc"></div>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q637bLq5/1/**

Comment: thank you! and this right:-1000px is it a good practise for this? should I use another value? thank you again!

Comment: Give it in `%` say `-150%`.